# WordPress admin panel is not loading correctly

Tags: wordpress

My WordPress admin panel is not loading and it is broken. When checking the console there were two console errors with a 503 error code. I know this is a temporary error but want to fix this one. This is the detailed error.

[image]

```
GET https://example.com/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=1&dir=ltr&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=dashicons,admin-bar,common,forms,admin-menu,dashboard,list-tables,edit,revisions,media,themes,about,nav-menus,wp-pointer,widgets&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=,site-icon,l10n,buttons,wp-auth-check,wp-color-picker,media-views,wp-jquery-ui-dialog,wp-components&ver=6.1.1 net::ERR_ABORTED 503
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated. I tried reinstalling WordPress, increasing the memory limit, etc. But still the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seeing the same thing today on a WP site. Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: Mine is also load-styles.php but it is Error 500.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is related htaccess. Kindly remove your existing htaccess and add default htaccess.

Default htaccess code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Comment: brilliant! this works